# Leaflet Map code copied from View-source: not working

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I was trying to use a ready Leaflet Map example, based here:

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Select/SelectPoints3.html

It hovers all points within 150 miles from the mouse click on the map.
As you can see the link on the website works perfectly. unlike to my local file.

I copied a whole code from this example into my local file and save it as a .html code.
All javascript files has been deliberately copied (however, they appear as a links, so it wasn't necessary to copy them onto my hard drive.

One file, that I had to copy was BaseBallFinal.json, including the data of all placemarks provided.

I am really confused, because the file extension .html means, that there is no php code there, so everything should be transferred easily. Unfortunately I have a blank map with clear marker once click somewhere.
On the contrary the map provided under the link above features everything what I need.

Could you explain me, what is wrong in this operation? Why the
            var url = "BaseBallFinal.json"; is not working at all?

It looks like this part of the code affect a latter sections, being unavailable and invisible.[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes  I've got quite a few:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/mariuszk/Desktop/BaseBallFinal.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
BaseBallFinal.json:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
150miles.html:62 You clicked the map at LAT: 40.212440718286466 and LONG: -78.57421875000001
150miles.html:89 Uncaught ReferenceError: sites is not defined
 ...

What should I do then?

Thanks

Comment: You're not going to be able to *easily* load the JSON file the way you're currently doing it without using a web server, due to cross origin resource sharing policies in most browsers. So for starters, I would assign a variable to the JSON within your existing script (i.e., `var data = /* the JSON file contents */`) and remove the AJAX call. Otherwise, try using a web server.

Comment: The code /* JSON filename */ doesn't work, so another option is i.e localhost. Is there another command in JS enabling me to run this map at some point? I will need it offline I am afraid. Cheers

Comment: Paste the contents of the JSON file where @AndroidNoobie wrote `/* the JSON file contents */`

Comment: @peeebeee I know this solution. I have been doing several times. I though a filename at first thing, although you are right. It looks like it's only one way to keep it running offline. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MariuszKrukar. Please have a look at my answer and check if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copy pasting the JSON via console's network you do not need to use jquery at all. Just import the GEOJSON like this:

```
import json from "./BaseBallFinal.json";
```

and use this code

```
sites = L.geoJson(json, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: 4, //expressed in pixels circle size
      color: "red",
      stroke: true,
      weight: 7, //outline width  increased width to look like a filled circle.
      fillOpcaity: 1
    });
  }
});
```

instead of

```
var promise = $.getJSON(url);
    promise.then(function(data) {

        sites = L.geoJson(data, {

            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                radius: 4, //expressed in pixels circle size
                color: "red", 
                stroke: true,
                weight: 7,      //outline width  increased width to look like a filled circle.
                fillOpcaity: 1
                });
                }
        });
   ...
}
```

The rest of code remains pretty much the same. I used es6.
Just for your notice I downloaded and tested it locally and it works as expected.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/selectpoints3-hxb29)