# Leaflet Map JS console issues after view-source copying

Tags: javascript, console, leaflet

I have a problem with using the Leaflet JS map when copying code from view-source:

According to my previous question:

[Leaflet Map code copied from View-source: not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555420/leaflet-map-code-copied-from-view-source-not-working)

It looks like I require a web server,

Unfortunately It is not working in Localhost too.

After using the javascript code from the web I always get a lot of issues in my console.

I copy deliberately each single line of the code, taking into account any links. Now I don't understand where the problem lies.

In the web server someone's code looks clear and console is clear.

like here:

https://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/kml.html

Once I copy all stuff on my drive and put it into the Wampp localhost I got a lot of errors in my console as per in the picture below:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///U:/Work/Leaflet/KML/LotA.kml'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https. KML.js:31 GET
>   file:///U:/Work/Leaflet/KML/LotA.kml net::ERR_FAILED

The code KML.js works on the web server and it's exactly the same as in my file!

Could you clarify for me please? Can I rut it on the localhost?

Do you know how to copy the code correctly? What stuff I have forgotten?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the KML file from your console's network tab, store it locally and then copy paste the client side code.

Note that this example is using a really old version of leaflet, 0.7.x

You can see the example in the following [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/load-a-kml-on-leaflet-07x-y7s0o)

**Edit**: 
I checked it locally and you are right regarding the previous library.
I made a plunker that seems to work locally using **leaflet omnivore** library to visualize a kml. I ran it with npm's [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) and seems be working.

```
var runLayer = omnivore.kml('test.kml').addTo(map).on('ready', function () {
    map.fitBounds(runLayer.getBounds());
});
```

Alternate [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/K4SVJlyedUFO8ufKOLI3?p=preview)

Comment: Not working when download all files to the directory. This is why I am wondering why. Your example is not only one, that doesn't work. The issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: I tried another way with another library. Please have a look.

Comment: I checked. Now I have a clear map without .kml
My console says:

testkmlleaflet.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/mariuszk/Desktop/test.kml' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
test.kml:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

test.kml has been copied alongside with index.html with map and js links provided.

Comment: Yeah, It works at localhost. Thank you for your help. It looks like the file must be callet always index.html instead i.e leafletKML.html. The host seeks an index.html as a default file and treat it as a web server. Otherwise you are redirected to the directory.

Comment: Yes. Always check at localhost or using a library like npm's serve.